# Virtual function taking parameters of base class type

Tags: c++, virtual

what's wrong with the polymorphism here?

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    virtual void dosomething(const A& ob) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int y;
    void dosomething(const A& ob) { // I assume this will work (base class accepting a derived class by reference)
        x += ob.x;
        y += ob.y; // error: const class A has no memeber named 'y'
        cout<<x<<"    "<<y;
    }
};


int main()
{
    B s, m;
    s.x = 3;
    s.y = 9;
    m.x = 3;
    m.y = 9;

    s.dosomething(m);
}
```

i tried using pointer instead of reference, and still not working
should i override the function?

Comment: Variables aren't treated the same way as virtual functions; they are checked at compile time. This is a consequence of the C++ Memory Model. You would have to do a cast to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dosomething()` accepts a reference to the `A` portion of an object.  `A` does not have a member named `y`, just like the compiler error says.  Only `B` has a `y` member.

Imagine there is another class `C` that also derived from `A` but not `B`, where `C` does not have a `y` member either.  What do you think would happen if a `C` object were passed to `B::dosomething()`?

```
class C : public A
{
public:
    int z;
    void dosomething(const A& ob) { ... }
};
```

```
B b;
C c;
b.dosomething(c);
```

It would not work.  `B::dosomething()` can accept a `C` object as input, but there is still no `y` member for `B::dosomething()` to read from.

So, you must use a type-cast inside of `B::dosomething()` to check if the input `obj` is actually derived from `B` before accessing its `y` member:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    int y;
    void dosomething(const A& ob) {
        x += ob.x;
        const B *b = dynamic_cast<const B*>(&ob);
        if (b) y += b->y;
        cout << x << "    " << y;
    }
};
```